# Google calendar API- Trying to get API but showing the 403 error

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, calendar

I'm trying to get the events from my organisation's Gmail ID. I'm using a service account to get other member's events without authentication but when I try to do it, it shows an error like

```
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 403,
            "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
            "errors": [
            {
                "message": "The request is missing a valid API key.",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "forbidden"
            }
            ],
            "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
        }
    }
```

The error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\Documents\mY_projecT\calender\newfile.py", line 21, in <module>
    singleEvents=True).execute()
                       ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\googleapiclient\_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 938, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/viewcalendar%40cloud.com/events?timeMin=2023-05-08T07%3A51%3A41.003169Z&timeMax=2023-05-15T07%3A51%3A41.003169Z&maxResults=2500&singleEvents=true&alt=json returned "Not Found". Details: 
"[{'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'notFound', 'message': 'Not Found'}]">
```

I gave the correct calendarID, and shared and gave permission to view my calendar. This is the code:

```
        from google.oauth2 import service_account
        from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
        from googleapiclient.discovery import build
        import datetime
        import pytz

        # API setup
        SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']

        # Create a credentials object for the service account
        creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            'keyfile.json', scopes=SCOPES)


        # Get the service object for the Google Calendar API
        def get_service():
            """
            Create and return the Google Calendar API service object
            """
            service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=creds)
            return service


        def get_events(calendar_id, date_str):
            try:
                # Set the working hours as 10am to 7pm IST
                tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

                # Parse the date string provided by the user
                date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str, '%Y-%m-%d').date()

                start_time = tz.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time(hour=10)))
                end_time = tz.localize(datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time(hour=19)))

                # Call the Calendar API
                service = get_service()
                events_result = service.events().list(calendarId=calendar_id,
                                                    timeMin=start_time.isoformat(),
                                                    timeMax=end_time.isoformat(),
                                                    singleEvents=True,
                                                    orderBy='startTime').execute()
                events = events_result.get('items', [])

                # Get event details
                for event in events:
                    start = event['start'].get('dateTime', event['start'].get('date'))
                    starttime = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(start).astimezone(tz)
                    end = event['end'].get('dateTime', event['end'].get('date'))
                    endtime = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(end).astimezone(tz)
                    print(f"Event: {event['summary']}")
                    print(f"Start Time: {starttime.strftime('%I:%M %p')}")
                    print(f"End Time: {endtime.strftime('%I:%M %p')}")
                    print(f"Description: {event.get('description', '')}")
                    print(f"Location: {event.get('location', '')}")
                    print(f"Attendees: {', '.join([attendee.get('email', '') for attendee in event.get('attendees', [])])}")
                    print("\n")

            except HttpError as error:
                print('An error occurred: %s' % error)


        if __name__ == '__main__':
            # Prompt the user for the calendar ID and date
            calendar_id = input("Enter the calendar ID: ")
            date_str = input("Enter the date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")

            # Get the events and print them
            get_events(calendar_id, date_str)
```

I would like to extract the event from id. Any advice would be appreciated.